# How to fire jQuery function only for certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried all the solutions I can find to achieve this, but had no luck.

This code is currently working for creating tooltips from title attributes. I'm trying to make it only run when an element has a particular class `.tooltipit`, rather than on all elements with title attributes.

You can see where I've tried to fire the function inside the class selector (commented out toward the end) which I expected to work, but doesn't.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    // textFrom : String, the attribute from which the text
    //            should come,
    // delta :    String or Number, the distance from the cursor at
    //            which the tooltip should appear
    function instantTooltips(textFrom, delta) {
        // if delta exists, and can be parsed to a number, we use it,
        // otherwise we use the default of 5:
        delta = parseFloat(delta) ? parseFloat(delta) : 5;

        // function to handle repositioning of the created tooltip:
        function reposition(e) {
            // get the tooltip element:
            var tooltip = this.nextSibling;
            // setting the position according to the position of the
            // pointer:
            // tooltip.style.top = (e.pageY + delta) + 'px';
            // tooltip.style.left = (e.pageX + delta) + 'px';
            // tooltip.style.top = (e.pageY + delta - 190) + 'px';
            // tooltip.style.left = (e.pageX + delta - 200) + 'px';
        }

        // get all elements that have an attribute from which we
        // want to get the tooltip text from:
        var toTitle = document.querySelectorAll('[' + textFrom + ']'),
        //create a span element:
        span = document.createElement('span'),
        // find if we should use textContent or innerText (IE):
        textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        // caching variables for use in the upcoming forEach:
        parent, spanClone;
        // adding a class-name (for CSS styling):
        span.classList.add('createdTooltip');
        // iterating over each of the elements with a title attribute:
        [].forEach.call(toTitle, function(elem) {
            // reference to the element's parentNode:
            parent = elem.parentNode;
            // cloning the span, to avoid creating multiple elements:
            spanClone = span.cloneNode();
            // setting the text of the cloned span to the text
            // of the attribute from which the text should be taken:
            spanClone[textProp] = elem.getAttribute(textFrom);

            // inserting the created/cloned span into the
            // document, after the element:
            parent.insertBefore(spanClone, elem.nextSibling);

            // binding the reposition function to the mousemove
            // event:
            elem.addEventListener('mousemove', reposition);

            // we're setting textFrom attribute to an empty string
            // so that the CSS will still apply, but which
            // shouldl still not be shown by the browser:
            elem.setAttribute(textFrom, '');
        });
    }

    // $('.tooltipit').each(function() {
    //  instantTooltips('title', 15);
    // });

    // calling the function:
    instantTooltips('title', 15);

});
```

Comment: ... i mean... if you read the function you're executing, you'd see it is clearly using the first argument to determine what attribute to select by, and has no way of doing additional filtering other than by modifying hte function itself. Doing something with jquery before or after the function will have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your querySelector is `[title]` (all elements that have a title attribute).  It should work if you provide a class name as well, as you have requested, for example:

```
var toTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipit[' + textFrom + ']');
```

Would only select those page elements with class='tooltipit' and having a title attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite it to a proper jQuery plugin, and everything is a lot easier

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.instantTooltips = function(delta) {
    delta = parseFloat(delta) || 5;

    return this.each(function() {
      var span = $('<span />', {
        text: $(this).attr('title'),
        css: {
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          display: 'none'
        },
        'class': 'createdTooltip'
      });

      $(this).on({
        mousemove: function(e) {
          $(this).prev().css({
            top: e.pageY + delta,
            left: e.pageX + delta
          });
        },
        mouseenter: function() {
          $(this).prev().show();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          $(this).prev().hide();
        }
      }).before(span);
    });
  }

  $('.tooltip').instantTooltips(15)

});
```

```css
.createdTooltip {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip" title="show this">Mouse here for tooltip !</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="nope" title="show this">This does not have the class !</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
$('.tooltipit').each(function() {
  $(this).on('mouseenter', function(){
    instantTooltips('title', 15);
  }
});
```